# Fitting two non-linear models to data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nonlinear-optimization, lmfit

Following the example is given in [`lmfit`](http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/parameters.html), I am trying to set up an example which is similar to my problem. My problem originally is that in my data I can fit two or three models, while my model is highly non-linear but it has for each model just a single free parameter.

**My example similar to `lmfit` documentation:**

```
x = np.linspace(0, 15, 301)
data = (5. * np.sin(2 * x - 0.1) * np.exp(-x*x*0.025) +(-2.6 * np.sin(-0.6 * x + 1.5) * np.exp(-x*x*3.0)+np.random.normal(size=len(x), scale=0.2) ))

def fcn2min(params, x, data):
    model=0
    for i in range(2):
        exec("amp_%d=%s"%(i+1,repr(params['amp_%d'%(i+1)].value)))
        exec("shift_%d=%s"%(i+1,repr(params['shift_%d'%(i+1)].value)))
        exec("omega_%d=%s"%(i+1,repr(params['omega_%d'%(i+1)].value)))
        exec("decay_%d=%s"%(i+1,repr(params['decay_%d'%(i+1)].value)))
        model += eval("amp_%d"%(i+1)) * np.sin(x * eval("omega_%d"%(i+1)) + eval("shift_%d"%(i+1))) * np.exp(-x*x*eval("decay_%d"%(i+1)))
    return (model-data)/data

params=Parameters()
for i in range(2):
    params.add('amp_%d'%(i+1),   value= 10,  vary=True, min=-3, max=3)
    params.add('decay_%d'%(i+1), value= 0.1,vary=True,min=0,max=4.)
    params.add('shift_%d'%(i+1), value= 0.0, vary=True,min=-np.pi, max=np.pi)
    params.add('omega_%d'%(i+1), value= 3.0, vary=True,min=-2.5, max=2.5)

result = minimize(fcn2min, params, args=(x, data),method='nelder')
```

The obtained rsults:

```
final = data + result.residual

# write error report
report_fit(params)
[[Variables]]
    amp_1:    -1.74789852 (init= 3)
    decay_1:   0.05493661 (init= 0.1)
    shift_1:   0.07807319 (init= 0)
    omega_1:  -2.00291964 (init= 2.5)
    amp_2:    -1.30857699 (init= 3)
    decay_2:   0.82303744 (init= 0.1)
    shift_2:  -0.04742474 (init= 0)
    omega_2:   2.44085535 (init= 2.5)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
```

The free parameters look completely off however on the final results plot it is clear it follows the distribution of data but the amplitudes are not quite right

```
try:
    import pylab
    pylab.plot(x, data, 'k+')
    pylab.plot(x, final, 'r')
    pylab.show()
except:
    pass
```

Any suggestion for the modification of the code in order to get the right results?
[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Have you tried another method apart from "nelder"?

Comment: @Cleb yes I did. They return different values but still off from input parameters!

Comment: Ok, then one more thing: You write that you have only 1 free parameter but you set "vary" to True for all 4. Do I misunderstand something there?

Comment: @Cleb you are right but my model is more complicated than this. since in the lmfit it could recover the free parameters well for this example I thought maybe I could try first with this example.

Comment: I added a modified version as an answer. It works fine for me; let me know whether that solves your problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the issue. I am not sure about the purpose of the line

```
return (model-data)/data
```

but it should just be

```
return (model-data)
```

since that it what you want to minimize.

Furthermore, you should also choose initial values that are in the range. The modified code will result in the following output:

```
[[Variables]]
    amp_1:     5.23253723 (init= 10)
    decay_1:   0.02762246 (init= 0.1)
    shift_1:  -0.40774606 (init= 0)
    omega_1:   2.06744256 (init= 3)
    amp_2:     2.49467996 (init= 10)
    decay_2:   0.39205207 (init= 0.1)
    shift_2:   0.23347938 (init= 0)
    omega_2:  -0.71995187 (init= 3)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
```

[image: The plot then looks like this:]

Here is the entire code:

```
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, report_fit
import numpy as np

#http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/parameters.html

# create data to be fitted

x = np.linspace(0, 15, 301)
data = (5. * np.sin(2 * x - 0.1) * np.exp(-x*x*0.025) +
(-2.6 * np.sin(-0.6 * x + 1.5) * np.exp(-x*x*3.0)+np.random.normal(size=len(x), scale=0.2) ))

def fcn2min(params, x, data):
    model=0
    for i in range(2):
        exec("amp_%d=%s"%(i+1,repr(params['amp_%d'%(i+1)].value)))
        exec("shift_%d=%s"%(i+1,repr(params['shift_%d'%(i+1)].value)))
        exec("omega_%d=%s"%(i+1,repr(params['omega_%d'%(i+1)].value)))
        exec("decay_%d=%s"%(i+1,repr(params['decay_%d'%(i+1)].value)))
        model += eval("amp_%d"%(i+1)) * np.sin(x * eval("omega_%d"%(i+1)) + eval("shift_%d"%(i+1))) * np.exp(-x*x*eval("decay_%d"%(i+1)))
    return (model-data)#/data

params=Parameters()
for i in range(2):
    params.add('amp_%d'%(i+1),   value= 10,  vary=True, min=0, max=13)
    params.add('decay_%d'%(i+1), value= 0.1,vary=True,min=0,max=1.4)
    params.add('shift_%d'%(i+1), value= 0.0, vary=True,min=-np.pi, max=np.pi)
    params.add('omega_%d'%(i+1), value= 3.0, vary=True,min=-3.5, max=3.5)

result = minimize(fcn2min, params, args=(x, data),method='nelder')

final = data + result.residual
report_fit(params)
try:
    import pylab
    pylab.plot(x, data, 'k+')
    pylab.plot(x, final, 'r')
    pylab.show()
except:
    pass
```

Comment: thanks but still the values for `amp_2`,  `decay_2` and `shift_2` are biased from the input values that generated data.

Comment: What do you mean by "biased"? Could you make a list of your expected output, maybe as an edit in your question?

Comment: I mean the estimated values are not close to inputs!

Comment: Because you can describe the model reasonable well with less parameters than you actually vary. Therefore, the solution is not unique. You can constrain the range of your parameters much more and then would end up with your expected parameters. The fit now looks perfect, but you could get the same quality with other parameter combinations as well.

Comment: I concur but I am also wondering whether weighting the data or using other approaches might return more accurate results or as you said setting rigid bounds might ?

Comment: That depends on your purpose, what you want to do with these parameters which is kind of beyond the scope of this question. My answer just improved the fitting results - which you asked for - the interpretation is yours ;) And you want to apply it to another model anyway, as far as I understood?! What should be added to get this answer accepted?